# Using Tomcat server for production - Ideal configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

Consider an webservice application (No sessions used) with around 10000 users and some 300 concurrent connections in peak period.

1. What kind of server configuration(In terms of RAM mainly) I can use?
2. Do I need cluster/load balance?

Answer (score 2):

RAM/CPU? Clustering? Load balancing? Only you can know. I've seen RAM occupation vary from a few megabytes to several hundreds, even for what seemed to be simple applications. A lot depends on what libraries you'll be loading. Same for CPU. There is no substiture for profiling a web application's performances. Start from a sample configuration, get some workload test software like JMeter (but there are many, the choice might depend on what your webservice does), create a decently average weight testing script and launch 50, 100, 150 threads. Keep your java virtual machine monitored (one free tool might be javamelody, and is both free and lightweight, but there are others) and check your logs if it crashes. Then make your proper calculations based on the response times and the machine's status when under load.